# Programatically setting the pixmap of a QLabel in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

The Widget we should use to show pictures is a QLabel. we can do it directly from QtCreator, by setting its pixmap property.

we should first create a resource file and then add the image to that resource file. To create a Qt Resource File, we go to the menus: File > Qt > Qt Resource File.

we can set the image of the QLabel using Qt Creator...

but i would want to change the pic according to some input from the user

i tried to do the following :

```
#include "form1.h"
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"
#include "ui_form1.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap * mypix = new QPixmap(":/karim/test.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(mypix);
    delete mypix;
}
```

but i got this error

```
..\Project\form.cpp: In constructor 'Form::Form(QWidget*)':

..\Project\form.cpp:12: error: no matching function for call to 'QLabel::setPixmap(QPixmap*&)'

c:\QtSDK\Simulator\Qt\mingw\include/QtGui/qlabel.h:123: note: candidates are: void QLabel::setPixmap(const QPixmap&)
```

what could be the problem ?

Comment: Given that you misunderstood the signature of the `setPixmap`-function, you should first learn the basics of C++.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The signature of the method you are trying to use is

> setPixmap ( const QPixmap & )

but you are passing in a pointer. Try using a value instead.

```
QPixmap mypix (":/karim/test.png");
ui->label->setPixmap(mypix);
```

Comment: Shouldn't QObjects be created on the heap anyway?

Comment: @OrcunC When I update the image with another image, the previous image doesn't clear. Any idea how to clear the pixmap before setting new image?

Comment: Dewsworld Im having the same issue...It looks like the parent widget is not updating...If you fixed it, please post =)

Comment: OK, heres the answer:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653114/display-image-in-qt-to-fit-label-size          thanks

Comment: `ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap(":/karim/test.png"));` is enough. Run qMake before to make sure your resources are correctly added to the compile steps.