# qt load image from resource: No input files specified error

Tags: c++, qt, qpixmap, qlabel

please note: QT newbie

I am attempting to display a PNG on a qLabel using the setPixmap function.

*note: PNG dimensions < Label dimensions*

Following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913575/programatically-setting-the-pixmap-of-a-qlabel-in-qt), it is supposed to display the image, but I have no luck.

I have attempted many examples, from using QImage to using GraphicsViews,etc.

I have gotten this image to show by specifying the full path in the `QPixmap pixmap("full_path_here")`, thus wanting to get rid of the full path, attempted adding this image to a resource fill, aka `.qrc` but the error below persists, I have no idea why.

**ERROR**: `/opt/qt/Qt5.7.0/5.7/gcc_64/bin/rcc:-1: error: No input files specified.`

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{


    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap mypix (":/back.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(mypix);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

**.qrc resource file**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>back.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

**mainwindow.ui**

```
<widget class="QLabel" name="label">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>121</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
```

**Project Location:**

```
ll /home/cx/qt-projects/VPN/

total 48
drwxrwxr-x 1 cx cx   162 Oct  5 15:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 cx cx    90 Oct  5 12:21 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx  1514 Oct  5 15:33 back.png
drwxrwxr-x 1 cx cx   108 Oct  5 12:12 .git/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   172 Oct  5 10:41 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   393 Oct  5 15:53 mainwindow.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   399 Oct  5 15:25 mainwindow.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx  3134 Oct  5 12:21 mainwindow.ui
drwxrwxr-x 1 cx cx     8 Oct  5 12:11 res/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx   400 Oct  5 12:12 VPN.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 cx cx 24064 Oct  5 12:35 VPN.pro.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your qrc file to:

```
<!DOCTYPE RCC>
<RCC version="1.0">
<qresource>
<file>back.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file path in `.qrc` file must be locatable on the filesystem by RCC compiler. E.g. for example if your file exists one directory up then you could just do following

```
<RCC>
    <qresource>
        <file>../back.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

In your example RCC compiler is looking for file in `/back.png` path and probably it doesn't exist there