# QLabel updates its minum size after setting a pixmap

Tags: qt

I want to fill a resizable area with an image, and use an expandable QLabel to show the image. I use the following code

1. Fetch QLabel size by using its width and height property
2. Resample the input image to fit within the size
3. Create a pixmap

Now, QLabel forces its size to fit the pixmap, thus it is impossible to shrink it. Shrinking it should trigger a new pixmap (with another size), to be set. I am open to another solution than using a QLabel. Ideally, I would like to have something like `gtk_drawing_area`.

Comment: Do any of the suggested solutions in here work? [Display image in Qt to fit label size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653114/display-image-in-qt-to-fit-label-size)

Comment: This seems relevant as well: [Qt: resizing a QLabel containing a QPixmap while keeping its aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211982/qt-resizing-a-qlabel-containing-a-qpixmap-while-keeping-its-aspect-ratio/22618496#22618496)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I could subclass `QWidget` and override `paintEvent`, like so:

```cpp
class image_view:public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit image_view(QWidget* parent): QWidget{parent}{}

    void set_pixmap(QPixmap&& pixmap)
    { m_image_data = std::move(pixmap); }

private:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*) override
    {
        QPainter p{this};
        p.drawPixmap(0, 0, m_image_data);
    }

    QPixmap m_image_data;
};
```

This behaves exactly as intended.